# How old are computers in "The 100"

Tags: the-100

In the show "The 100" there are computers everywhere, in the Ark, the Mountain, the ship, etc. I even remember a laptop in the Mountain and an iPod on Alpha.

How old are these computers? If I follow correctly, some of them might be more than 200 years old. Meanwhile I'm lucky if my iPhone lasts 4 years. Does it make any sense?

Comment: If your iPhone was unused and kept in its box, it would be usable decades later

Comment: I still have my first iPhone (3G) which, apart from being a bit slow, still works, *and it's over 10 years old*. and I used it for over six years until i got a new one

Comment: But in the show, the mountain men used their computers for 100 years. Same for Alpha. And the computers aboard ships were used all the time ...

Comment: The only reason your iPhone "only lasts 4 years" is because *by design* these devices are made to be flash and wear out quickly.  Look up "planned obsolescence."  In a post-apocalyptic, resource-poor scenario (such as life on the Ark) focus would have quickly shifted to utility and longevity out of necessity.  The tech would not change or improve as quickly, but it would also be built to last longer.  Batteries would go back to being replaceable, for example, so you can swap out a dying battery without replacing the whole device.

Comment: The reasons most computers fail is due to either: Old Batteries that leak damaging the circuits, High heat damaging components, Moisture causing corrosion to the circuit boards. If you keep them cool and dry, and monitor any batteries (if it has them) Computers should last for many years. I have no doubt the ones on the station are also built to last a long time. If not being used often, as long as its kept moisture free, it should last. High heat can fry components, or many large heat variations, (hot/cold/hot/cold) can weaken the connections due to expansion/contraction.

Answer (score 1):

If the Tech was plausibly usable at this time, it would have to have been important in 2050ish before the bombs that our tech was long lasting, I believe it on the Ark; they were built for space, so I get if Ark tech lasted. However if the tech on the ground was plausibly this long lasting, it would mean that in 30 Years from now in 2023, we would no longer be practicing physical obsolescence in our technology. Which would require you to believe that our society and tech industry would shift gears pretty soon to today. So it's more of a question about the kind of society The 100 imagines happens between now and the show's 2050 bombs. Maybe the AI helped up shift to more robust tech before it sent the bombs, preparing the world to be able to use her highly advanced tech when there were no more means of production. Or maybe the preppers of the 2050s left enough robust tech around for this. Anythings possible, I wonder if the flashbacks before the bombs would tell us anything. Certainly the Second Dawn had good tech, but we didn't have their bunker until later, but they weren't the only ones prepping.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This answer seems heavy on speculation and light on hard evidence, though. Note that in order for an answer to a question like this to be well-received here, it typically needs to provide at least some evidence from an official source to back up whatever it's postulating.